# Change variable used in a For loop

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking to assign a different text to 3 RadioButton by looking into a tab where 3 names are stocked, using a For loop to get each value of the tab 1 by 1 but is there a way to change the variable I'm aiming at for each loop.

My variables are named "option1", "option2", "option3" so is there a way in vb.net to change the variable name ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please select either VBA or VB.NET - you can't be using both...

Answer (score 0):

So i guess i found smth, with a container

```
Dim options() As String = {"MR", "MME", "MLLE"}
For i As Integer = 0 To genreGrp.Controls.Count - 1
     genreGrp.Controls(i).Text = options(i)
Next
```

Sorry i just start vb.net :/